# elmt.style.backgroundImage Resize Picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

I don't know how to resize a picture to width = 90, height = 127 in

```
elmt.style.backgroundImage = "url("+ string1 +")";
```

with string1 = "images/♠" + random1 + ".jpg";  (random1 is 1, 2, 3 or 4)

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `background-size` property to resize the image.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500)';
div.style.backgroundSize = '50px 50px';
div.style.width = '50px';
div.style.height = '50px';
```

```html
<div></div>
```